# Tangent space of a smooth manifold is independent of parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

From Milnor's "Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint":

"Now let us define the tangent space $T M _x$ for an arbitrary smooth
manifold $M \subset R^k$. Choose a parametrization
$g: U\rightarrow M \subset R^k$
of a neighborhood $g(U)$ of $x$ in $M$, with $g(u) = x$.

Here U is an open
subset of $R^m$. Think of $g$ as a mapping from $U$ to $R^k$, so that the derivative
$$dg_u : R^m\rightarrow R^k$$
is defined. Set $TM_x$ equal to the image $dg_u(R^m)$".

We shall prove that the tangent space is well defined, therefore we want to show that it doesn't depend on the particular parametrization we choose.

"Let $h : V \rightarrow M \subset R^k$ be another
parametrization of a neighborhood $h(V)$ of $x$ in $M$, and let $v = h^{-1}(x)$.

Then $h^{-1}\circ g$ maps some neighborhood $U_1$, of $u$ diffeomorphically onto
a neighborhood $V_1$, of $v$. We obtain the commutative diagrams:

[image: From "Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint"-Milnor]

The second diagram is one of linear maps, where $d(h^{-1}\circ g)_u$ is invertible. It follows that: $$dg_u(R^m)=dh_v(R^m)"$$

I need a clarification solely on the conclusion, in regards to why this argument implies that the images are equal.

Comment: After some thought I came to the conclusion that we can apply chain rule to $d(h^{-1}\circ g)_u$ obtaining: $$d(h^{-1}\circ g)_u=dh^{-1}_{g(u)}\circ dg_u$$ Which, following the diagram gives us $$dh^{-1}_{g(u)}(dg_u(R^m))=R^m$$
Therefore, we have $dh_{v}(R^m)\subset dg_u(R^m)$.
If we apply the same logic with the isomorphism $d(g^{-1}\circ h)_v$ we obtain the inclusion of images in the other direction, giving us equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment:
We can apply chain rule to $d(h^{-1}\circ g)_u$ obtaining $$d(h^{-1}\circ g)_u=dh^{-1}_{g(u)}\circ dg_u$$ Which, following the diagram, gives us $$dh^{-1}_{g(u)}(dg_u(R^m))=R^m$$
Therefore, we have $dh_{v}(R^m)\subset dg_u(R^m)$.
If we apply the same logic with the isomorphism $d(g^{-1}\circ h)_v$ we obtain the inclusion of images in the other direction, giving us equality, thus $$dg_u(R^m)=dh_v(R^m)$$
That is, different parametrizations give us the same tangent space.